# What is the Ghost Design Pattern?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns

Someone recently asked a question about the Ghost Design Pattern - I have not seen this before.

What is the Ghost Design Pattern and how is it implemented?  I can only find snippets on the web in reference to it.

Comment: During architecture interviews I used to ask people, "so, can you tell me anything about the LeftHandedSpinWidget design pattern?" and watch them wrestle with the confusion. There is no LeftHandedSpinWidget design pattern.

Comment: @Swingline That's cruel.  Ghost is a genuine pattern though.

Comment: Really sad to talk about a pattern that does not exists, I mean, almost everyone agrees that the "Ghost pattern" refers to a Proxy or Lazy Loading but are not 100% sure. 
GoF said : 
The pattern's name conveys the essence of the pattern succinctly. A good name is vital, because it will become part of your design vocabulary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only reference I've ever heard to a Design Pattern and 'Ghost' is in [Lazy-Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Ghost).

Since Lazy-loading involves only loading the object when it's actually needed, you can think of it as a 'Ghost' until then.  You can see its outline, but can't really use it until it's loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Ghosts are mentioned in PoEAA, pp 202, 206-14. A ghost is a lazy loaded object that contains just enough info to instantiate itself on demand. They can be useful because they can trigger a bulk load of similar ghosts on the first access if they register themselves with a loader (dunno if Fowler mentions that bit though).

Answer (score 4):

It's not in GOF nor Fowler PoEAA, the only thing I can think of it as something similar its a Proxy for lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just created one and then realized it was a Ghost pattern after asking [a question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21069231/938236). Follow that link for the original PHP code, here's a pseudo-code version:

```
// A "cheap" class
class Namespace_Original
  {
  // The expensive, uninitialised object
  private Original

  // The "cheap" data needed to initialize Original
  private Data

  // Constructor for the cheap class
  public Namespace_Original(Data)
    {
    this.Data = Data
    }

  // Whenever you call a method of Original
  public __call(method_name, method_data)
    {
    // Create the expensive object only the first time it's going to be used
    if (empty(this.Original))
      this.Original = new Original(this.Data);

    // Call the Original's method with it's arguments
    this.Original.name( method_data );
    }
  }
```

When you initialize this *cheap* class, nothing is created inside it. It's when you actually call a method that the "Original" object gets created, if there was none, and data retrieved from that. It makes you not to initialize *Original* if you're not going to use it, providing it's an expensive operation.