# PHP: Database-Connection in Class or global

Tags: php, database, class

I'm working on a project for school (Deadline in June; plenty of time given ^^).

At the moment there is a database in the conf.php (every other .php includes this one; it has a variable which references a mysqli-object) and i am accessing the database in every method of a classs via "global $db_conn;".
The problem is, if I open just the class.php, it doesn't include the conf.php and it throws errors. So I thought about adding an private instance/static variable for the mysqli-Object with EVERY object.
This is not working (unexpected T_NEW):

```
class foo{
    private static $db_conn = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
}
```

How do you handle db-connections?
How would you handle this specific problem?

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you make your db connection a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class *and* you have an  [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/autoload) function, then you can just have a dbconnection property in each of your classes which is set during construction.

e.g.

```
class DBConnection{

  private static $instance;

  private function __construct(){
    //make your db connnection
  }

  public static function get_connection(){
    if(empty self::$instance) self::$instance = new DBConnection;
    return self::$instance;
  }
}

class Foo {

  private $db;

  function __construct(){
    $this->db=DBConnection::get_connection();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a great idea. I think i will give it a try. ^^ Thank you

Comment: @Mathlight, the short answer is: because it introduces global state in the application. It's basically the same as using global variable. All the same penalties apply. To see a much better approach, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) though, you will nee to understand how anonymous function work.

Comment: @tereško, thanks for the link. I'm watching the Google video now, very interesting

Answer (score 0):

you could use `include_once` the conf.php file in both your other files and the class file. that way you always have the contents (and db reference).

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem is that all the class and the conf.php are in different folders and sub-folders. So i can't use the include_once or require_once. but i'll restructure my project, so that all the import stuff is in the same folder, that should fix my problem. Thank you