# How to use singleton as connection in php class

Tags: php, class, singleton, database-connection

I am new to OOP php , now i trying to understand the overall pattern but i struck somewhere at sharing database connection for all classes. **I am referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297677/954220)** which make db connection a singleton class and call it at each constructor.

This is the singleton database class , should do the connect part and i have my autoload set

```
class DatabaseConnection{

  private static $instance;
  private $dbc;

  private function __construct(){
   $this->dbc = mysqli_connect(...);
  }

  public static function connectDb(){
    if(empty(self::$instance)){
    self::$instance = new DatabaseConnection;
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

This is  my class , i tried to connect db in the constructor

```
class SlideShow {

    private $dbc;
    private $result;

    function __construct() {
        $this->dbc=DatabaseConnection::connectDb();
        $this->result=$this->getSlideShow();
    }

    private function getSlideShow(){
        $q = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);
            //the error stated $dbc , object given
    }

}
```

I am having a problem in my SlideShow class which saying the **$dbc is object'** , my question is am i doing it right ? If yes , how do i fix the stuff , i had a hard time to understand the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297677/954220) posted

Comment: You have a double equals on this line: `$this->dbc==DatabaseConnection::connectDb();`

Comment: I'm sorry i miss typed my question , corrected!

Comment: **Don't use singletons.** Ever. It is an antipattern, which create a global state in your applications. Instead you should learn about dependency injection and how to implement it in your code. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) post might give you some pointers (of course, you would have to alter for use with MySQLi instead of PDO, but that is an insignificant detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
    $this->result = mysqli_query($this->dbc->dbc, $q);
                                            ^^^^----
```

Note the doubled dbc in the object reference. First one is the private `dbc` attribute in your `Slideshow` class, the second dbc is the actual DB handle that's created in your DB class.

Comment: Alright I found it , and I need to change the private $dbc to public $dbc , and last question ... Did i achieve the pattern mentioned in that answer i referring to?

Comment: Here's the barebones version of a singleton in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954304/abstract-singleton-pattern-class?rq=1