# pdo connection class?

Tags: php, oop

I am tring to learn about PDO people have said its easy and the best way to interact with the database, but im not finding it easy. can any help?

Connection.php

```
<?php

class Connection {
    public function dbConnect() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=lr", "root", "");
    }
}

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('pdo.php');
$obj = new Connection();

$obj->dbConnect();
echo 'hello';
?>
```

This works but its too simple. what is the best way?

Should i have my connection in its own class and extend it to the rest of my classes or should i use a global variable to connect? or is there another way better way? Thanks

Comment: please clarify the question ! if this works what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: You are just connecting and not using the connection for anything? And you are not storing the returned result in a variable. This looks like a "Hello world" with extra unused code. What are you trying to learn?

Comment: What is your motivation to create a connection class? What should it do? I never heard this is necessary with PDO.

Comment: hi basically all the tutorials i have seen are outdated and use mysql_*. So now i need to learn either mysqli or PDO and since im learning oop im going to try pdo(unsuccessfully). I dont understand how to put the connection into a class

Comment: did you read this one already ? http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly setting up PDO connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-setting-up-pdo-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just creating a connection and not telling us what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to post, update, delete something in the database or what?

The best I can do since you aren't asking anything is link you to a website that will try to teach you the basics. I hope you have used databases before though.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: i just want a connection for now but i want it in a class for oop. like my post. but when i create a user class and any other classes how do i best use the connection

Comment: You could create an instance of this class inside those other classes that you want using this class or you could extend them. Eg. class User extends Connection{//You implementation};  Then all you have to do is call the dbConnect function, storing what it returns in a variable and use that variable as you link to the database. This all can happen in the extended class. That is just on of the solutions.

Comment: Thanks that was the info i was looking for.

Comment: Please, stop linking people to low quality tutsplus articles. This one is filled with bad practices and bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed easy, in a way.
Using global variable would be easier. and of course you need to use correct filenames for include.

Straight from [PDO tag wiki:](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

pdo.php

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lr;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
```

index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('pdo.php');

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stm->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo "Hello $name";
```

Answer (score -5):

Check this out (https://gist.github.com/dirte/5331258):

```
<?php
/*
 * PDO Database class
 *
 * Usage:
 * $db = Database::getInstance();
 * Return array of query results, normal statement: $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'Bob'");
 * Return array of query results, prepared statement (named params): $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = :name", array(":name" => "matthew"));
 * Return int of last insert result row id: $db->lastInsertId()
 * Return int of last query result row count: $db->lastQueryRowCount()
 */
class Database {

    /*
     * Instance of the database class
     *
     * @static Database $instance
     */
    private static $instance;

    /*
     * Database connection
     *
     * @access private
     * @var PDO $connection
     */
    private $connection;

    /*
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param $dsn The Data Source Name. eg, "mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306"
     * @param $username
     * @param $password
     */
    private function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".DBNAME.";host=".HOST.";port=".PORT, USER, PASS, array(
                                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                                    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => DBTIMEOUT));
        if (empty($this->connection)) {
            trigger_error("Error #D001:", E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    /*
     * Gets an instance of the Database class
     *
     * @static $instance
     * @return Database An instance of the database singleton class
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new Database();
            } catch (\PDOException $e) {
                trigger_error("Error #D002: ".$e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /*
     * Runs a query using the current connection to the database
     *
     * @param string query
     * @param array $args An array of arguments for the sanitization such as array(":name" => "foo")
     * @return array Containing all the remaining rows in the result set.
     */
    public function query($query, $args = false) {
        $tokens = array_map('trim',explode(" ",trim($query)));
        $query = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\t"), " ", $query);
        $query = str_replace('    ', ' ', $query);
        try {
            // Prepare results
            $results=false;

            // Allow for rollback if query fails
            $this->connection->beginTransaction();

            // Prepared statements
            $sth = $this->connection->prepare($query);

            // Execute prepared statement, with or without arguments
            if (empty($args)) {
                $sth->execute();
            } else {
                $multiple = false;
                foreach ($args as $arg) {
                    if (!is_array($arg)) { continue; }
                    $multiple = true;
                    break;
                }
                if ($multiple) {
                    $i=0;$j=count($args);
                    foreach ($args as $arg) {
                        foreach ($arg as $k=>$v) {
                            if ($v === "NULL") { $arg[$k] = NULL; }
                        }
                        $sth->execute($arg);
                        $i++;
                    }
                } else {
                    $i=0;$j=count($args);
                    foreach ($args as $a=>$arg) {
                        if ($arg === "NULL") {$args[$a] = NULL;}
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $sth->execute($args);
                }
            }
            // SELECT: Return array of data or false if 0 rows
            if ($tokens[0] == "SELECT") {
                $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $results = $sth->fetchAll();
            }
            // INSERT/UPDATE/REPLACE: Return number of affected rows / array of affected ids ?
            // Note: lastInsertId only works if ID col on table is auto_incremented
            elseif ($tokens[0] == "INSERT"
                    || $tokens[0] == "UPDATE"
                    || $tokens[0] == "REPLACE") {

                // If sessions table, assume key = return id
                $results = $this->connection->lastInsertId();
            }
            // Else: Return number of affected rows
            else {
                $results = $sth->rowCount();
            }
            // Attempt to commit changes, triggers exception if fails
            $this->connection->commit();

        // Rollback changes on failure
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $msg = 'query(): ***** Caught Exception! Rolling back changes *****'.PHP_EOL.'<hr />Query:<pre>'.$query.'</pre>'.PHP_EOL.'<hr />Exception Message:<pre>'.$e->getMessage().'</pre><hr />'.PHP_EOL;
            $this->connection->rollBack();
            trigger_error($msg, E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }

        return $results;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the last insert result row id
     *
     * @return int of last insert result row id
     */
    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->connection->lastInsertId();
    }

    /*
     * Returns the last query result row count
     *
     * @return int of last query result row count
     */
    public function lastQueryRowCount() {
        return $this->connection->lastQueryRowCount();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: How's this going to help? This user is not even catching the errors thrown. I think this will be a mouthful and what if they don't know that they'll be using the singleton design pattern? I think this user just wants the basics.

Comment: thanks thats what i want. the basics so i can learn and build from it

Comment: I dont think its that bad :) shows how to use the different PDO methods