# call PHP PDO wrapper class from another class

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo

I'm planning to use a PHP PDO wrapper class from here: http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

I initialized the class with:
`$db = new db("mysql:host=$sitedbHost;port=3306;dbname=$sitedbName", "$sitedbUser", "$sitedbPass");`

The problem is, that I don't like the idea to make `global $db` on every function on my other classes like this:

```
class User
{
    function getUserDomains($user_id)
    {
        global $db;
        return $db->select("domains");
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) somewhat relevant.

Comment: PDO wrapper? You won't beat the Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer - http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html

Answer (score 2):

If you class requires it in order to work, you can **inject** it in the constructor:

```
class User {

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}
```

You can then access the database object from `$this->db`. (Note, I assumed `$db` is an instance of the `Database` class. Change it as appropriate).

Comment: @МиленМихалев: "Not working" is not a valid PHP error. What isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

Here is something for you:

Check new [PDO Class Wrapper on GitHub](https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/PDO_Class_Wrapper)

Answer (score -3):

> I don't like the idea to make global $db on every function on my other classes

Well, make it global in constructor only (or pass it as a parameter), and then use as a class variable,

```
return $this->db->select("domains");
```

Honestly, you can't avoid passing $db to the function somehow. There is no magic. Whatever fashionable way you choose, you'll end up with setting your $db variable this way or another, no matter how it's called, "dependence injection", "global" or "use the Force, Luke".

I'd vote for `global` as it's plain and simple.

By the way, this framework is inflexible and insecure. Better use [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) as it's way more secure and flexible

Comment: -1 just for that last line. Sorry, `global` is not plain, not simple.

Comment: Insecure? Why do you think that it's insecure?

Comment: @МиленМихалев it doesn't protect your identifiers for example (table and field names). It's inflexible too. Do you use IN() operator in your queries?

Comment: @Your Common Sense this safeMysql class is made by you? So.. if I use this class there will be no need to escape, sanitize strings and etc because of the placeholders and it will protect the queries against sql attacks?

Comment: @МиленМихалев yes. It does proper formatting for all possible data types, not only strings and numbers like PDO. And thus makes a query fully protected. There are many other benefits too. I'd be glad to have any feedback from you if you decide to try it.

Comment: @МиленМихалев strictly speaking, in case of PDO you don't need to escape, sanitize strings too. The only difference is that PDO doesn't have placeholders for the complex types such as arrays for SET, IN and identifiers.