# translate from PDO to MySQLI

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

after a lot of hours troubleshooting i found that my hoster (hosting2go.nl) does not support PDO::mysql they just dont installd the driver so my Model.php in my MVC framework is screwed. I solved the problems with my database-conection. The problem is that i am completely new to mysqli and justr cant find out how to make my model.php (writen for PDO::mysql) writen for Mysqli (instead of PDO) i hope you guys can help me out...
My code:

|ORIGINAL PDO MODEL.PHP|

```
class Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
        $this->data = $_POST;
    }

public function query( $data = array(), $query){
    try{
            $result = $this -> db -> prepare($query);
            $result->execute($data);
            $result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

|My Database-connection|

```
class Database extends mysqli {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("localhost","root","","bartsite");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}
```

|This is what i made of my model.php FOR MYSQLI|

```
class Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
        $this->data = $_POST;
    }
    public function query( $data = array(), $query){
        try{
                echo $query;
                $result = $this -> db -> prepare($query);
                $result = $this -> db -> query($data);
                $result->fetch_all();
//$result->execute($data);
//$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}
```

|usefull part f the controller|

```
public function index(){
    $data = $this->posts->getAllPosts();
    var_dump($data);
    $this->view->render("posts/index",$data);
    return true;
}
```

|posts.models.php|
class postsModel extends Model
{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getAllPosts(){
    $result = $this->query(
        array(),
        "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY  id DESC"
    );
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) useful

Comment: thats not my problem, i m pressued to use mysqli and have to rewrite my model.php i want some help with that. the dbcon is no prob.

Comment: and after my prob. i will definitly have a look at your link teresko

Comment: i rewrote my database class, now i hve to adjust my model to it.

Comment: is it real example of Model class or just a skecth? If so, can we see a more sensible function that does something useful? Just to be able to translate it

Comment: added all what is ness. it`s the complete model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have in your mind to change hosting in future i suggest you to implement PDO interface by yourself. After your hoster add PDO or you change hoster you can switch to native PDO painless.

**UPD:**
Pros: 
+ you can test your own PDO implementation to be compatible with canonical PDO
+ so you can easy migrate

Cons:
- a lot of work to do

Possible hack: implement PDO interface partly, only that stuff you really use

**UPD-2**
you can just get new hosting and forget about this one if it will be more cost-effective to you to do not mess with mysqli_* and other. Also it depends on your code base: there is no problem to change few methods or so, but not a huge cms or stuff like that. So the choice is up to you.

**UPD-3**

replace try-catch block in `Model` with this code

```
echo $query;
$stmnt = $this -> db -> prepare($query);
// bind params to statement from $data here
if (false === $stmnt->execute()) {
    // error
    echo $e;
    return;
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: yea but i already paid for a year,.. and it`s never wrong to learn something new.

Comment: and this was my last hosting with this company.

Comment: is there any refunds or something?

Comment: it's just a 35 euro. not to much for the lesson that you have to check available extensions and other stuff first. i had such experience too, so i can recommend to forget about that bastard and do not mess with PDO implementation. Your time probably costs more.

Comment: true that but i`m not planning to change the hosting. not the question ill just want to know how to adjust my model.

Comment: `        }catch(PDOException $e){` <- this will not work without PDO installed.

Comment: ok that worked ! but ill have the error:Warning: Missing argument 2 for Model::query(), called in /home/vhosts/broersma-state.nl/httpdocs/app/models/posts.model.php on line 18 and defined in /home/vhosts/broersma-state.nl/httpdocs/app/model.php on line 12
NULL NULL

Comment: public function query( $data = array(), $query){ <- wrong, http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default, try public function query( $data, $query){

Comment: probably you have to pass two arguments on <skiped>/app/models/posts.model.php on line 18

Comment: @user2057856 as I told you in my answer, it won't work. You could scarcely make it work with empty data only.

Comment: my bad. mysqli::query doesn't accept args, so you have to bind args to query first

Comment: ah that`s the lat prob i think

Comment: i think if you are not proficient in software development (maybe you are but in other lang) the @YourCommonSense give you good example and maybe you should try his solution and even accept it if it will work for you

Comment: i`m just starting in with programming and thanks you`ve helped me alot

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find out how to make my model.php writen for Mysqli

As a matter of fact, you can't do it without a LOT of pain. Mysqli neither have bindValue, not it can return you an array of arbitrary structure.

Nevertheless, your Model class is wrong.

- first, for some reason it has $data as first parameter, making you to write it always.
- next, you are catching an exception to echo it out, which is a big no-no
- finally, I hope you are creating only one instance of Model class as well as one of whatever Database class.

So, let me suggest you [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) instead, which is built upon mysqli but being more user friendly and safe than PDO.

Say, for postsModel

```
class postsModel {

    function __construct(safeMysql $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getAllPosts(){
        return $this->db->getAll("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC")
    }
}

$db = new safeMysql();
$model = new postsModel($db);
$posts = $model->getAllPosts();
```