# What is the proper way to share objects between classes?

Tags: php

I've came across a problem in an application I am building and that is: how can I create a single database connection for use across multiple classes?

After reading upon this a little bit, different posts/people seem to be telling me different things. Use of `$_GLOBAL` or the `global` keyword would be one way to do it, but that has it's own issues.

Other threads on Stackoverflow have suggested `Singletons` as a way of doing so, but also stated that it wouldn't be the proper way of achieving a shared property of an instance.

So, what would be the **best** way of achieving this, say for a Database Controller or a Session Controller?

Comment: [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with a container. Look into [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16605563/5816907) provides its bests, also DI as johnconde mentioned

Comment: @JohnConde Dependency Injection is perfect and works very well with my application, thanks! Can you write as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

Globals and singletons are way of the past. [Dependenci Injection](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/dependency-injection) is todays best approach. Of course, there will be many people that wouldn't agree with me, so at the end, choise is yours.

I would recommend using DI implementation from [Nette Framework](https://nette.org/en/) - https://github.com/nette/di Why this one? Because it will do lot of work for you. For example autogenerating of Dependency Injection Container or autogenerating class factories from simple interface.