# PDO incorporation within class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having some issue understanding this. I'd like to start re-writing some old MySQL function code PDO. The way it was set up, is that an external file containing this line (among other things):

```
// db.php file   

$DB = new dbConnect(SERVER,DB,USER,PASSWORD,3306);

function my_autoloader($class)
{
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/".'class.' . $class . '.php' );
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Which would create a connection to my database. This is included at the very top of my pages and would also load all my classes. Now, if I want to create a new connection using PDO, I would do the following:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.SERVER.';dbname='.DB.';charset=utf8',USER, PASSWORD);
```

However, I cannot have this line of code on a separate file and call PDO from within a class like the following:

```
require_once 'db.php';
class info
{

    protected $ID;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->ID = $id; // 
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM job";
        $q = $conn->query($query);
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //do something with $data

    }
}
```

Does this mean I have to establish a connection in the constructor by means of aggregation like the following?

```
require_once 'db.php';
class info
{
    protected $ID;
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->ID = $id; // 
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.SERVER.';dbname='.DB.';charset=utf8',USER, PASSWORD);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM job";
        $q = $this->pdo->query($query);
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or is there another way of doing this that I'm not aware of. It seems tedious trying to re-write all of my classes to incorporate this.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to rewrite your mysql_* functions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly setting up PDO connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-setting-up-pdo-connection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating the database connection inside the constructor, it's better to make it a dependency:

```
public function __construct(PDO $db, $id)
{
    $this->pdo = $db;
    $this->ID = $id;
}
```

To use it, you would do:

```
// $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.SERVER.';dbname='.DB.';charset=utf8',USER, PASSWORD);
$info = new info($db, '123');
echo $info->getName();
```

The chief advantage of this approach is that you no longer have any configuration stored inside your class. Additionally, you can pass anything that implements `PDO` as well, enabling unit testing with mocked databases.

Comment: I had thought of that but that would mean that i'd have to do that for all my instances... This was why I had created the database connection in my constructor.

Comment: @Dimitri Not sure if this applies to you, but you could create a super class that accepts both db and id (protected) in the constructor ... then all your classes extend from that.

Comment: @Dimitri Also, I fail to see how creating the db connection inside each constructor is less work than passing the db connection to each constructor.

Comment: Hmm, that's an idea actually. It would have to be properly coordinated. Perhaps have my db connection as the hierarchy and everything else follows down...

Comment: I thought about what I wrote, it makes no difference... I'd have to do the same amount of work anyway.

Comment: @Dimitri Cool. Feel free to ask me more if you're not sure. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a connection to a database, you should do so in a singleton class. You only ever want to open one connection to a database. For example:

```
public class database
{
    static $instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
          if($self::$instance == null)
          {
                $self::$instance = new PDO(); // string value here.
          }
          return $instance;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the `database::getInstance()` method from anywhere in your class, and you don't need to keep re-writing your connection code.

PS: I'm aware this singleton isn't thread safe. I was simply trying to highlight the concept to OP.

Comment: This is interesting. Would you be able to create a working example with the implementation and how to use it? I'm just trying to see the full picture here...
The aggregation method was going to create thousands of connections if I were to run an instance in a loop...

Comment: @Chris: yep, but don't forget that PDO is a class, so rather than having a wrapper class, you could extend instead. Doing it this way means that all of PDO's methods will be inherited by `database`, rather than having to add wrapper methods in the child.

Comment: @dimitri I think it's probably better if you try and implement it yourself, and also look at halfer's comment which is very important!

Comment: I'll give it a shot. What confused me is that I completely missed the `new PDO()` and was trying to figure out where to put it. I'll come with an example and post some code. Instead of wrapping the PDO class, I'll extend it.

Comment: Double -1: PHP objects outside of extensions are thread-safe by default, singleton is a nightmare to test in this form, so, to be avoided at all costs if you're planning on using that database class as more than just a PDO instance storage.

Comment: @SébasienRenauld If singleton is to be avoided, how else would you go about it? The whole issue was to be able to call PDO from within  any class. I don't see why anyone would use the database class as more than just an instance storage.

Comment: @Dimitri The alternative oft-recommended by anti-singleton, unit-test enthusiasts is to pass parameters around. So, you'd either pass a connection in at construction time or to the getter method. Frankly, I think the testability hit for using a singleton (and occasionally even a global variable -- the horror!) is pretty insignificant.

Comment: Establishing a connection in your constructor, wouldn't that have a major impact? If I were to instansiate my job class after pulling up 10,000 records, wouldn't that create 10,000 useless connections? Or are we fall in the same pit?

Comment: @Dimitri Not *establishing* a connection during object construction; passing in an *already established* connection, either at construction or to the static getter. Unit testing is alleged by most unit-test fanatics to be far easier when you move things out of the ambient context and explicitly demand they be passed in as parameters; it presumably allows you, when building a unit test for `someMethod()`, to not only know *what* `someMethod()` needs at a single glance, but to give `someMethod()` test parameters without building a whole context.

Comment: Really? It's 2013. We have bigger fish to fry than singletons. It's basically an accepted axiom that singletons are bad... Not only are [Static Methods Considered Harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html), but [Global State and Singletons Are Brittle](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/), so the prevailing wisdom is [Singletons vs Global State, Choose Neither](http://www.phparch.com/2010/03/static-methods-vs-singletons-choose-neither/)...

Comment: I don't think you can just categorically deny the value of these design patterns. The only argument I hear is that singletons are harder to test. What if I've put in the work to set up a testing environment? It also depends on what you're writing. So quit the hating. There's plenty of room for singletons AND dependency injection.

Comment: @AliGangji: That's not the only argument, and it's not the only one included in those links. Ex: Singletons make interfaces that lie (you can't trust the interface to tell you what the code needs or may be doing). It is spooky action at a distance (which is always bad). It kills the idempotence of code (which is strongly tied to code quality). It reduces flexibility of code. It increases both temporal and global coupling (which are both strongly tied to overall code quality). Instead, compositional patterns are strongly recommended because they don't suffer from any of these problems...

Comment: I think the use of Singleton depends on its uses. In this case, it's merely just a storage place for my db connection and nothing more. As mentioned before, PDO is a class and can be extended. The only major draw-back I see to that is redesigning almost everything I've written to incorporate the extension. If this is the case, perhaps due to my lack of experience, wouldn't that make PDO my "core" class? That would still mean I'd have to pass variables in my class' constructor. Perhaps that's where the case of singleton would come into play...

Comment: @ircmaxell I agree that dependency injection is the best practice. I just feel that the enforcement of that best practice is taken to an extreme. I know you're getting votes for these, but in my opinion we don't need downvotes and anti-singleton comments every time a singleton shows up. Just post an anwser using dependency injection and explain why it's better.

Answer (score 0):

here's my first attempt:

```
class database extends PDO {

        protected static $instance;

        protected function __construct(){}

        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if(empty(self::$instance))
            {
                 $db_info = array(
                                "db_host" => SERVER,
                                "db_port" => PORT,
                                "db_user" => USER,
                                "db_pass" => PASSWORD,
                                "db_name" => DB);

                 self::$instance = new Database("mysql:host=".$db_info['db_host'].';port='.$db_info['db_port'].';dbname='.$db_info['db_name'], $db_info['db_user'], $db_info['db_pass']);

             }
             return self::$instance;
        }
}

class info
{
    protected $ID;
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->ID = $id; // 
        $this->pdo = database::getInstance();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM job";
        $q = $this->pdo->query($query);
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // do something
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct as I have no ways of testing this for the moment. Would this be considered correct?