# fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, prepare

http://steliyanportfolio.zzl.org/

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO ( 'localhost', '869276_amsteljlo', 'st08553813', 'steliyanportfolio_zzl_myportfolio' );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    exit ( 'Database error.' );
}
```

portfolio php

```
include_once ('connection.php');
var_dump($pdo);
class Portfolio {
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM portfolio");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: public function fetch_data($portfolio_id){
   global $pdo;

    
   $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE portfolio_id = ?");
   $query->bindValue(1,$portfolio_id);
   $query->execute();
    
   return $query->fetch();
  } 
    }

?>

Comment: Try `$pdo->execute();` and `return $pdo->fetchAll();`.  I don't have too much experience with PDO but that would seem to be the problem to me.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't make your connection a global.  I would but that in a function and return the variable.  Then just call that connection function and throw that in an object.

Comment: did not help give me an idea without PDO

Comment: what do you mean I'm a newbie

Comment: I don't know what `idea without PDO` means.

Comment: Can you write the code as you think it is right according to you

Comment: replace `$query->execute();` with `$pdo->execute();` and replace `return $query->fetchAll();` with `return $pdo->fetchAll();`

Comment: nothing changed same mistake

Comment: My code is fine, you are doing something wrong with `$pdo = new PDO ( 'localhost', '869276_amsteljlo', 'st08553813', 'steliyanportfolio_zzl_myportfolio' );`  according to the error on your site.

Comment: @СтелиянСтоянов , please stop using globals. If you need to provide PDO instance to a class, instead try something like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208 (also, watch the two linked lectures).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO ( 'localhost', '869276_amsteljlo', 'st08553813', 'steliyanportfolio_zzl_myportfolio' );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    exit ( 'Database error.' );
}
```

With:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=steliyanportfolio_zzl_myportfolio;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = '869276_amsteljlo';
$password = 'st08553813';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        exit ( 'Database error.' );
    }
```

Overall, your code should look like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=steliyanportfolio_zzl_myportfolio;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = '869276_amsteljlo';
    $password = 'st08553813';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        exit ( 'Database error.' );
    }

    var_dump($pdo);
class Portfolio {
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM portfolio");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given in /www/zzl.org/s/t/e/steliyanportfolio/htdocs/include/portfolio.php on line 8
NULL
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /www/zzl.org/s/t/e/steliyanportfolio/htdocs/include/portfolio.php on line 17

Comment: Works fine on my server so check any code errors.  On the bottom of your page it shows database error which shows you have some code working.

Comment: on my locol machine works fine on web server dont work

Comment: Make sure you have a database on your server and that the credentials for your database are correct

Comment: this is a link to the whole system I can not handle I'm desperate  http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1375477064

Comment: I thank all changed with another hosting apparently there was a problem  http://stportfolio.comuf.com/

Comment: Glad you got it working!  I like your site.  Very well designed!  Awesome job with the jQuery and HTML5 :)