# PHP OOP - Classes that need db access

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm starting to write some PHP classes that are reusable across projects but had a quick question about handling dependencies.

I'm writing a pagination class that I want to grab results from a mysql database. Now obviously this will rely on a Database object/class. I have a custom written database class that I want to use but then I hit a problem. I was planning to pass the db object in as a paramter but of course, because it is my own db class - it will have custom methods that not everyone else will have.

So my pagination class might run:

```
$db->run_query($sql);
```

Obviously, someone else might have a db class that instead uses:

```
$db->query($sql);
```

What's the best way to deal with this? I could run my query before but then I'm making more work than I want to for the user. Is the lesser re-usability just something I'll have to live with if I want to make it a one-line command?

It's similar with other examples, so I may want a Page object to use an HTMLHelper but then the page class hits a wall in terms of it being easily reusable.

This is more for personal projects at the moment but releasing these classes is something that is likely to happen in the future.

Comment: That's what interfaces are for

Comment: And Adapters as well.

Comment: Sorry guys, could either of you elaborate? I'm looking at interfaces and adapters (adapter pattern?) but I'm not quite getting where this will solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly set up a PDO connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the response is :

[What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

You may have to reconsider your conception.