# Mysql connection + OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a php class, this is a fragment of him:

```
<?
class labelUpdater
{
    private static $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "password");
    if (!$link) {
        die('Connection error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Success';
    mysql_close($link);die;
}
?>
```

When I launch it, I'm getting this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/..../labelUpdater.php on line 6
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use OOP with MySQL, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which you should be doing anyway.

Comment: Go learn PHP OO basics and then come back. This is a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) might be useful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just write code inside a `class`, you have to enter it into a `function`.

Also, it's a better practice to use `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Further more, notice that the `mysql_` extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5. You should use newer and safer extensions such as [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).