# how can i call my database class in different class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to learn OOP along with PDO and prepared statements. I've made a database class which I believe is very simple.

I have a posts class and I want to echo all the data in this database, I have a constructor method which I want to call the database connection on however I believe I am doing this wrong and probably going about it the wrong way  as I am getting the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in E:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\class.Register.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\class.Register.php on line 18

Any ideas on how I should go about calling my database correctly

posts.php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

class Posts {

protected $Database;

     public function __construct() {
 $pdo = new Database();
     $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }

public function viewall() {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch(); 
    }
}
$run = new Users();
$run->viewall();
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php

class Database {
    public $dbo;

    public function __construct() {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'testdb';
        $user   = 'root';
        $pass   = '';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            //echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        
    }
    
     public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->pdo = null;
        //echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');`

Comment: Why do you define properties in your classes that you do not use? (`protected $Database;` and `public $dbo;`)

Comment: You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling the method 'viewall' within the 'Users' class. However in the code you've shown the method 'viewall' is a member of the 'Posts' class.

```
$run = new Users();
$run->viewall();
```

Also you're setting the 'pdo' property, even though it doesn't exist within the class.

```
$pdo = new Database();
$this->pdo = $pdo;
```

Try changing

```
class Posts {
```

to

```
class Users {
```

and

```
protected $Database;
```

to

```
protected $pdo;
```