# PDO database class returning empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a previous question on building a database class I was informed that I should switch to PDO for my static db class

This is what I have so far everything works except the dbDataArray prints out an empty array even when I know there is data in the table.

```
class db
{
    private static $connection;
    const __DB__HOST__      = __DB__HOST__;
    const __DB_USERNAME__   = __DB_USERNAME__;
    const __DB_PASSWORD__   = __DB_PASSWORD__;
    const __DB_NAME__       = __DB_NAME__;

    private static function getConnection() {
            if (self::$connection === null) {
                try {
                self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:__DB_NAME__=pdo;host=".__DB_HOST__, __DB_USERNAME__, __DB_PASSWORD__ );
                return self::$connection;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
        /*** close the database connection ***/
        //self::$connection = null;
    }

    //return all results from sqlquery in array
    public static function dbDataArray($sql_string){
        $conn = self::getConnection();
        $sth = $conn->prepare($sql_string);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't discard the exception and continue execution. How is your program meant to continue without a database connection? I'd highly recommend removing the `try` and entire `catch` block. You've also messed up the lazy-load approach. The `return` should be outside the `if` block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to build a static db class that I can access from any function outside of the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885421/trying-to-build-a-static-db-class-that-i-can-access-from-any-function-outside-of)

Comment: Thanks for the help Phil I am still learning PDO and I would call myself neophyte when it comes to OOP. I have written a few classes from scratch but nothing too complicated.

Comment: I've updated my answer on your previous question with some PDO specific information. Should help you out.

Comment: Thanks Phil I will return to that original question sorry for posting the second one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your getConnection code to:

```
self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".__DB_NAME__.";host=".__DB_HOST__, __DB_USERNAME__, __DB_PASSWORD__ );
```

Comment: that did the trick! Can't believe I missed that.  Now on to all of the other functions in the class!