# Class not found error

Tags: php, oop

I am having trouble getting my code to work, it worked fine before trying to segment it all up into separate class files. I am getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'UserMethods' not found in /var/www/EncoreCMS/test.php on line 25`. I have a `DatabaseConnections.php`file that contains the class and methods for establishing a connection to the database. There is also a `UserMethods.php` file that has the `retrievePassword()` method stored in the `UserMethods` class. My code is below:

DatabaseConnections.php:

```
<?php
require '/resources/library/DB.php';
class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private $conn = null;

        public function __construct(PDO $conn)
        {
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }

        protected function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }

?>
```

UserMethods.php:

```
<?php

class UserMethods extends DatabaseConnection
    {
        public function retrievePassword($userName) 
        {
            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`= :userName');
            $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $userName);
            $stmt->execute();
            $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            return $salt;
        }

        public function retrievePictures($userName)
        {
            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT `userName` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`= :userName');
            $stmt ->bindValue(':userName', $userName);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            return $user;
        }
    }

?>
```

test.php:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

require "$root/resources/library/DB.php";

function __autoload($class_name) 
    {
        //class directories
        $directorys = array(
            'Applications/Database/Classes/',
            'Applications/User/Classes/'
        );

        //for each directory
        foreach($directorys as $directory)
        {
            //see if the file exsists
            if(file_exists($directory.$class_name . '.php'))
            {
                require_once($directory.$class_name . '.php');
                //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else 
                return;
            }            
        }
    }
$userName = "testuser";
$a = new UserMethods($conn);
echo $a->retrievePassword($userName);
?>
```

Comment: Where do you load the class file? I see the attempt to instantiate it, and the autoload method but nothing that specifically states this autoload is hitting the UserMethods.php file. Also, why the redundancy in the directorys array?

Comment: I actually just figured it out I was calling the same directory twice I changed the second directory to `Applications/User/UserMethods but now I am getting a few more errors that I think I can resolve

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DatabaseConnection::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given, called in /var/www/EncoreCMS/test.php on line 25 and defined in /var/www/EncoreCMS/Applications/Database/Classes/DatabaseConnection.php on line 9`

Comment: You violate the `LSP` and `SRP` at the same time!!!

Comment: What do you mean I violate LSP and SRP

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Google for SOLID principles

Comment: My guess is your referring to the two methods in my `UserMethods.php` file. The `retrievePictures()` method I put in there to do some testing it was never going to be part of the real code. I am still a total beginner especially in OOP so any help is appreciated. I found a book on the SOLID principles I am reading up on. Is there any other problems you spot with the code that I am doing wrong I would like to learn to do things the right way first instead of relearning to break bad habits.

Comment: First of all, use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). As for PDO, you might benefit from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208). Oh .. and use absolute paths in the autoloader, or you will have very hard time in keeping track of directories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem see updated code