# Login & register user // PHP/MYSQL OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication, passwords

It's going to drive me crazy ... 
So, What am i doing wrong ? Where is my error ?

When i try to connect, it always show me the result where user and password are wrong even they're right ...

If someone has an idea to implement session also ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Peace & Unity !

Here's the beast !

### INDEX.PHP

```
<?php 

include_once('user.php');

if(isset($_POST[submit])){
    $name = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];


    $object = new User() ;
    $object->Login($name, $pass); 

    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    login : <input type="text" name="login" /><br>
    password : <input type="text" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="login" />

    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

## dbConnect.php

```
<?php 

class Connection {

    public function dbConnect(){

        return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname:test","root","");

        }


    }


?>
```

### USER.PHP

```
<?php 

include_once('dbConnect.php');

Class User {
    //Start Construct
    Private $db;

    public function __construct () {
            $this->db = new Connection();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();

        } 
// End Construct

public function Login($name, $pass) {

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user Where user_login=? AND user_pass=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $name);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "User Connected";
            }else{

                echo "Vachez ta mère";
                }


        }else{

            echo "Enter a valid Login and Password";
            }





    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled full error reporting? Also, you should set PDO to use exception for error handling and disable emulated prepares. [This tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) might help a bit. Oh, and the PDO instance would better passed as a dependency to `User` class constructor. To share the same PDO instance among multiple classes, you could employ [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i will check that !

Comment: The first link is exactly what i'have used to do my page. 
Could you more specific in _To share the same PDO instance among multiple classes, you could employ this approach_

Comment: Which part should I specify? It contained a link already.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but it's chinese for me, ;-)

Comment: to be more specific, it took me maybe 8 hours to code these 3 pages.

Comment: Then there is nothing I can do. You will probably be better off if you start reading [this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-PHP-5-3.productCd-0470413964.html).

Comment: I have already read this book [link](http://www.amazon.com/Expert-PHP-MySQL-Application-Development-ebook/dp/B00FJUFEKW/ref=sr_1_15?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1385297344&sr=1-15&keywords=php) and all i have done was basically based on this book and web research. So now, i'm stuck and you seem to be very good, why don't you tell what's going on this code ? 
thanks again for your very precious help

Comment: Try to change this: `if($st->rowCount() == 1){` to this: `if($st->rowCount() > 0){` just in case, if you allow duplicate usernames. Also note this: PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. Check if you connect to the DB and if the user exists in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Use    `$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user Where user_login=? AND user_pass=?");
      $st->execute(array($name, $pass));`

instead of
 `$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user Where user_login=? AND user_pass=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $name);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but it still not working ... I don't understand why ?

Comment: use if($st->rowCount() = 1){ instead of if($st->rowCount() == 1){ there are no double eguality in php

Comment: Are you sure of that ? 
It's not working also and make it worst, the index.php page does not load anymore.
Thanks for your answers anyway and thanks to help me

Answer (score -3):

You can use the tradational method like this :

> public function Login($name, $pass) {

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){
    $st = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user Where user_login=? AND user_pass=?");
    $count = mysql_fetch_rows($st);
    if($count == 1){
        echo "User Connected";
        $userSession = $_SESSION['user'];
        }else{

            echo "Vachez ta mère";
            }


    }else{

        echo "Enter a valid Login and Password";
        //header("location: index.php"); <- this can be used to redirect
        }





}
```

Comment: Why use `mysql_*` in PDO? Why suggest it?

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers.
I'm really a big noobs in php, i really want to know how to use OOP, that's why i'm not using the conventional method.

Comment: And for the mysql in the PDO, i read php manual for PDO instance and they  use it like that.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the questions, i was thinking about 
... new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; ... in the PDO, not in the procedural way example above