# Common parent classes

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have some variables and functions which need to be available for different classes. Hence, I put all definitions (Variables / functions) to some class:

```
class common_functions() {
    function __construct() {
        $this->define_variables();
        $this->connect_to_database();
        echo "EXEC";
    }
    function define_variables() {
        $this->var1 = "foo";
        $this->var2 = "bar";
    }
    function connect_to_database() {
        mysql_connect(...)
    }
    function do_something() {
        //...
    }
}
```

which is the parent of all the others:

```
class orders extends common_functions {

    private $order_item;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct()
        $order_item = new item();
    }
    function show_something() {
        echo $order_item->get_something()*$this->var1;
    }

}


class item extends common_functions {

    pivate $some_number;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct()
        $this->number = 123;
    }
    function get_something() {
        return $this->var2*$this->var1*$this->number;
    }

}


class some_other_class extends common_functions {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct()

    }

    // ..

}
```

However, as executing

```
$o = new order();
$o->show_something();
```

the output is

```
EXEC
EXEC
```

since the common_functions class is called twice. Especially also mysql-connection is established several times which is quite unefficient.

What I need is some technique so that all the functions and variables (and database-connections) from common_functions are available to all classes without the drawback that e.g. connect_to_database() is executed several times. Some ideas?

Comment: If two classes need a database connection, then it should be injected into their constructor as a dependency. To see a way for implementing that, take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208). Also, you should really stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd redesign my implementation. Why? Well because it seems to me that neither `some_other_class` nor `item` **is a** `common_functions`. However they both have `common_functions`. Thus I'd create only one instance of that class and pass it into the constructor.

Something like this:

```
class Item {

    private $common_functions;

    public function __construct($common_functions) {
        $this->common_functions = $common_functions;
    }

}

class Order {

    private $common_functions;

    public function __construct($common_functions) {
        $this->common_functions = $common_functions;
    }

}
```

What happens now is that both the `item` and `some_other_class` objects has a dependency which we inject to `common_functions`. This obviously means that you have to pass some values to the methods in common_functions but that is a very small price to pay considering what you gain from not inheriting common_functions, like only one db-connection.

Inheritance is cool but in practice it isn't used all that much. It's often much better compose objects than to inherit a bunch of stuff. When designing OO-classes always consider wether an objects relation is an `is a` or `has a` relation.

**So what you could do using the above example of the orders constructor is the following:**

```
class orders {

    private $common_functions;

    public function __construct($common_functions) {
        $this->common_functions = $common_functions;
        $order_item = new Item($common_functions);
    }

}
```

That way both `item` and `order` will share the same `common_functions` object.

Comment: yes, thats the point that all the functions have a "has a"-relation. However, I don't see how your suggestion works? How to make functions available in classes item oder some_other_class?

Answer (score -1):

Assign a static null variable initially in parent class and check if its null or not.

class common_functions {

```
private static $dbInstance = null;

function __construct() {

    if(self::$dbInstance == null) {
      self::$dbInstance = $this->connect_to_database();

    }
```

}
...

return the the database connection handler or any other than the null value in $this->connect_to_database();

Comment: however, $dbInstance will not be available to other classes than the one called the constructor?!

Comment: which means that finally every class need to established a db-connection again, as at my present implementation.

Comment: class common_functions {

    private static $dbInstance = null;

    function __construct() {

        if(self::$dbInstance == null) {
          self::$dbInstance = $this->connect_to_database();
          echo "EXEC";
        }
        else {
         echo "NOEXEC";
        }
  }

  function connect_to_database() {
       $dbh = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
       mysql_select_db('dbname', $dbh);
       return $dbh;
    }
        
} As of your implementation 
$t = new item();
$o = new order(); outputs EXEC NOEXEC connect_to_database() function will not be executed several times.