# php - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

hey i try to use the foreach function and i get this error...my code goes like this.

My index.php

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'kostas'));
if(!$user->count()) {
    echo "No user";
}else {
    foreach ($user->results() as $user) {
        # code...
        echo $user->username, '<br>';
    }
}
```

and my DB.php has those functions

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
            $_query, 
            $_error=false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count=0;
    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach ($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_reults = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            }else{
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];
            if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }
    public function error() {
        return $this->_error; 
    }
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
?>
```

Could you please tell me what possibly goes wrong here???
My database has already a table with the username kostas in the users table so it should returned the result corectly.

Comment: You have "$this->_reults" in code.. typo..

Comment: Wrong arguments passed to the class get() method will return a Boolean false that you aren't handling: it isn't the problem here, but you should address it

Comment: You could probably benefit from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11369360/727208) post.

Answer (score 1):

try different name for your variable

```
 foreach ($user->results() as $u) {
    //# code...
    echo $u->username, '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($user->results() as $user) {
```

You are using the same variable twice here, could that be the problem?

You could rename one of the variables. Here I renamed the first `$user` to `$userQuery`, as I think this is clearer:

```
$userQuery = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'kostas'));
if(!$userQuery->count()) {
    echo "No user";
}else {
    foreach ($userQuery->results() as $user) {
        # code...
        echo $user->username, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Or you can rename the variable in the foreach:

```
foreach ($user->results() as $usr) {
```

Comment: it was a silly mistake guys 

    $this->_reults = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

correct:

    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

thanks for answers anyway...