# OOP PHP load not returning correct object

Tags: php, oop, pdo

**Problem:** When I load model with `load` object, it will NOT return second model.

Take a look at class `Test` where I load model with `load` object. Code `$this->two` will return object One ( should load object Two ).

**Q:** How to solve this problem? I am open your suggestions/ideas/code

**Current Result:**

```
one is working
object(One)#3 (1) { ["error":"Model":private]=> NULL }
one is working
object(One)#4 (1) { ["error":"Model":private]=> NULL }
```

**Correct result:**

```
one is working
object(One)#3 (1) { ["error":"Model":private]=> NULL }
two is working
object(Two)#4 (1) { ["error":"Model":private]=> NULL }
```

**PHP:**

**one_model.php**

```
<?php

class One extends Model {

    public function test() {
        echo '<p>one is working</p>';
    }

}
```

**two_model.php**

```
<?php

class Two extends Model {

    public function test() {
        echo '<p>two is working</p>';
    }

}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public $load;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load = new Load();
    }

}

class Load {

    public function model($name) {
        if (!class_exists($name)) {
            require(strtolower($name) . '_model.php');
        }
        $model = new $name;
        return $model;
    }

}

class Model extends PDO {

    private $error;

    public function __construct() {

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8";
            parent::__construct($dsn, 'root', '', $options);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

class Test extends Controller {

    public $one;
    public $two;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->one = $this->load->model('one');
        $this->two = $this->load->model('two');
    }

    public function testing() {
        $this->one->test();
        var_dump($this->one);
        $this->two->test();
        var_dump($this->two);
    }

}

// Usage
$test = new Test();
$test->testing();
```

Comment: Are you sure the second model is saved correctly? Testing you code on my test server, it does give me the correct result.

Comment: Ignore that. I removed the PDO code because it didn't seem relevant to the test, but adding it seems to cause the problem. At least that's a good clue where the problem is :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that extending PDO is causing this problem. But I need it to extend for Model.

Comment: First of all, model should never extend PDO

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say "never", but in general I'd agree. Using dependency injection or even a database singleton would usually be my preference. Opening a separate connection for each model is sort of a waste of resources, since PHP code will rarely ever need more than one connection.

Comment: I have `PDO wrapper` in `model`, so I use my functions (`insert`, `select`, `delete`, ...) in every class witch extend `Model`.

Comment: In OOP `extends` stands for **"is a"**. So .. why the hell are you stating that "one" is "fashion model", and that "fashion model" is a "database abstraction". Because, sure as hell, what you refer to as "model"  has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved PDO wrapper from Model to separate class and create object for database connection.

Is this good approach ? Is this "`waste of resources`"?

```
class Database extends PDO {

    private $error;

    public function __construct() {

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8";
            parent::__construct($dsn, 'root', '', $options);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}


class Model {

    public $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

}
```

Comment: With the `ATTR_PERSISTENT` set to true, this wouldn't be too bad, for the reasons described in my answer, but for non-persistent code you want to avoid initializing more than one instance of PDO.

Comment: In general, though, persistent connections are pretty safe. Give them a shot on your web app and see how it preforms. Source: [http://bitfluxx.com/2008/04/11/why-you-should-use-persistent-connections-with-mysql.html](http://bitfluxx.com/2008/04/11/why-you-should-use-persistent-connections-with-mysql.html)

Comment: Where should I use `__dectructor` for closing connection? In `controller`/`database`/`model` class ?

Comment: Actually, persistent connections have been known to cause major issues on servers not set up to handle them. (Which, by default, they aren't.) The general wisdom is to avoid them unless you actually need them. No offense to your source there, but you should research the downsides better. - As for closing the connection, you don't need to. PHP closes all open connections automatically when the script ends, not to mention that when using persistent connections, they aren't actually closed. They remain open; persisting between requests.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) useful.  Also, your "new approach" is leaking the encapsulation.

Answer (score -1):

The problem there seems to be that you are passing `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` to the PDO constructor. This will tell PDO to cache and reuse connections - as you no doubt intended - but it also appears to cause PDO to produce clones of the first PDO instance generated within the scope of a single script, including the child class used to create that first instance. (Doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on this though.)

If you require persistent connections, my recommendation would be to define the models in a way that doesn't require them to be extended from PDO. That really shouldn't be a necessary in any case.

For example, if your code uses a CRUD model, abstracting that away from the model, and putting the database code into the base of *that* instead of the actual Model, might solve this nicely. For instance, given these as a base:

```
class DatabaseSingleton {
    private static $instance;

    public static function get() {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            $dsn = "mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8";
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

abstract class Crud {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = DatabaseSingleton::get();
    }

    public function create(...) {
        $this->pdo->...
    }
    public function retrieve(...) {
        $this->pdo->...
    }
    public function update(...) {
        $this->pdo->...
    }
    public function delete(...) {
        $this->pdo->...
    }
}
```

Then your models could simply be defined as children of:

```
abstract class Model extends Crud {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Etc...
    }
}
```

And the CRUD functionality defined in `Crud` would be available to to them, using the single PDO instance provided by the singleton.

Comment: @tereško And what exactly is wrong with using a singleton in this situation?

Comment: Same ting that is wrong with it in **every other** case: it creates tieght coupling and introduces global states.

Comment: No offense, but that kind of sounds like you're parroting the negative blogs/discussions on the subject. Care to be more precise? - Singletons have a bad rep, but I won't agree that they are bad overall. They have their uses. - In this case only one PDO instance will ever exist, enforced by the PDO class itself, effectively making *it* a Singleton even without the wrapper. It's also a stateless object, seeing as it's a direct representation of the database, making that a non-issue. PHP DB code is always going to be tightly coupled to one DBA or another. You can control that via config files.