# How can I use variable from class in another class

Tags: php, oop, singleton, crud

I wants to call methods in a class, using db connection from another class.

**`initializing.php`**

```
// load the configs, AFTER this I SHOULD HAVE CONSTANTS
require_once('myconfigs.php');

// load some function , some HELPER
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

// load the core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
$database = MySQLDatabaseConnection::connection();
```

**`the database.php`**

```
require_once('myconfigs.php');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'initializing.php');

class MySQLDatabaseConnection {

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct(){

    }

    private function __clone(){

    }

    public static function connection(){

        if ( !isset( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new MySQLi(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
            if ( self::$instance->connect_error ) {
                throw new Exception('MySQL connection failed: '. self::$instance->connect_error);
            }
        }

        return self::$instance;

    }



}
```

**`the listproducts.php`**

It is for some testing, after this in DbPlus class I want to create CRUD methods, but looks like simple echo doesnt works :/

```
require_once('initializing.php');

class DbPlus extends MySQLDatabaseConnection{

    public $database = parent::connection();

    public function read(){
        $query = "SELECT name, price_in, price_out, category_products_id FROM products";
        $data = $database->query($query);

        while ( $row = $data->fetch_object()) {
            echo $row->name;
        }
    }

}

$dbplus = new DbPLus;
$dbplus->read();
```

Im getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xxx\includes\listproducts.php on line 19

I dont have clue where does unexpected '(' comes from.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Please do not use global state to share DB connection between several instance. Instead use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some serious problems with your  **`listproducts.php`**

You should do this assignment on a `constructor`

```
public $database = parent::connection(); //<--- This gave you a syntax error.
```

Like this...

```
  public $database;
    function __construct()
    {
     $this->database = parent::connection();
    }
```

Next thing comes your `read()` , you need to make use of `$this` keyword..

Should be..

```
public function read(){
        $query = "SELECT name, price_in, price_out, category_products_id FROM products";
        $data = $this->database->query($query);   //<---- Do this way..
```

#### The fixed code..

```
<?php
require_once('initializing.php');

class DbPlus extends MySQLDatabaseConnection{

    public $database;
    function __construct()
    {
     $this->database = parent::connection();
    }

    public function read(){
        $query = "SELECT name, price_in, price_out, category_products_id FROM products";
        $data = $this->database->query($query);

        while ( $row = $data->fetch_object()) {
            echo $row->name;
        }
    }

}

$dbplus = new DbPLus;
$dbplus->read();
```

Comment: Reference from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated. `

Comment: Thanks for that Mark , It gave a parse error as the line of code was outside of the `constructor`, so that must be run-time  related right ?

Comment: The fact that it needs to ___execute___ `parent::connection();` to get the value to assign means that it needs run-time information in order to be evaluated

Comment: Thank you Mark , Any idea why was my answer downvoted ?

Comment: So Im a beginner, but if I got the point, parent::connection() should be executed, because it returns the connection, right?

Comment: @user3497923, The first comment on this answer by Mark explains why you got a parse error. Yeah you are right `parent::connection()` returns you the connection.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - no idea why the downvote, I countered it by upvoting

Comment: I didnt downvoted your answer, but I tried to upvote, but I dont have enough reps. Simple assignment public $database = parent::connection(); wont execute the method?

Comment: Once again I have to say :) The answer lies in this [**comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862399/how-can-i-use-variable-from-class-in-another-class/22862446?noredirect=1#comment34879576_22862446) by Mark. Let know if you find difficulty understanding it.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thank you for helping. Can you explain me, why cant I use **global $database;** inside the **DbPlus class** however I defined in the _initializing.php_ ?

Comment: Because that breaks your `OOP` , Also , the singleton pattern you have used is a bad practice. Please read this beautiful article. http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thank you, I will carefully read it, and make some practice. Do you have any idea(article, link['same_as_above'], book) how to keep alive db connection when with oop, without usin singleton? Thank you again

Comment: You need to look up on [**Persistent Database Connections**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php#features.persistent-connections)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and let me know :

```
$dbplus = new DbPLus();
$dbplus->read();
```

Also give us the PHP version you are using

Comment: The parenthesis doesn't matter :)