# Two DB::getIntance() running on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Hi I just want to know if is it possible to have different queries with DB::getInstance() value in query at the same time on the same page? and is it good practice to do? if Not can you show me the best practice?

I have update page (update.php) on my update page I have querying the part where you would get the id in the database.

this works fine.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];   
$agent = DB::getInstance()->get('agent', array('id', '=', $id));
```

Below of my update.php page is a drop down field where it will querying some part of my table data. for instance it is a director table where this user is belong.

But it does not work.

```
            $directors = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM directors");


             echo "<select name='director' id='director'>
                    <option value=''>".$agent->results()[0]->agent_name."</option>";

             foreach($directors->results() as $director){
                echo "<option value='$director->name'>".$director->name."</option>";
             }

             echo "</select>";
```

Thank you

Comment: Using `DB::getInstance()` (usage of `static`s) is always bad practice. http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain further?

Comment: @PeeHaa PHP can be used as a procedural language as well.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure but this question is tagged OOP instead of procedural.

Comment: @PeeHaa oh. Do you really trust in users tagging?

Comment: for your information Your common sense and @PeeHaa Im practicing OOP approach. if you cant seems to find this question a OOP code or you cannot answer this a right way. please dont answer because you can lead the users in bad way.

Comment: if you think that someone cannot answer your question the right way, then there is a possibility that something can be wrong with the question...

Comment: if you do not recommend singleton practice what is the best approach? @PeeHaa

Comment: @JaysonLacson You might want to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/508666

Answer (score -4):

Although it's impossible to answer your question directly, there are some directions

1. Don't use getinstance() method. it just makes no sense nowadays.
2. DON'T use get() method. It never had any sense at all.

If you want a singleton approach, then create a wrapper that already being a PDO instance. You may [find an example here.](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper/blob/master/bestpdo.php)

And you will be able to run any number of queries of any type:

```
$sql   = 'SELECT * FROM agent WHERE id = ?';
$agent = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$_GET['id']])->fetch();

$directors = DB::query("SELECT * FROM directors")->fetchAll();
```

It seems that you also mistaken in using query results

```
echo "<select name='director' id='director'>
    <option value=''>$agent->agent_name</option>";

foreach($directors as $director){
   echo "<option value='$director->name'>$director->name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I was new in oop I dont know what to do. do you have any tutorial of OOPHP with PDO?

Comment: You can just avoid OOP at all.

Comment: I edit my comment. sorry for my bad. thank you anyways!