# How to have children classes inherit MySQL Database connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, inheritance

I am using PHP 5.4.4 and I have a MySQL Database connection that I want to use for queries in the parent class and have that connection inherited by all children. I create a new instance of the parent and pass the db connection (`$handler`) as a parameter and the db connection becomes a property of the parent. When I create a new instance of a child I
thought the db connection would be inherited as a property of the child, however I can only make that happen when I pass it is a parameter to both the child and parent:: constructor functions. This seems redundant to me and I am wondering what I am missing since I am new to PHP OOP.

```
require "pdo_connect.php"; //mysql db connection

class newUser {
    public $timestamp;
    public $dbconn;

    public function __construct($handler) { 
        $this->timestamp = time();
        $this->dbconn = $handler;
    }

    public function showdbconn() {
        //use $this->dbconn for mysql query
        print_r($this->dbconn);
    }
}

class social extends newUser {

    public function __construct($handler) {
        $this->message = 'message';
        parent::__construct($handler);
    }

    public function test() {
        //use $this->dbconn for mysql query
        print_r($this->dbconn);
    }
}

$x = new newUser($handler);
$x->showdbconn();  

$y = new social($handler); //why pass to child if passed to parent?
$y->test();
```

Comment: If you are creating two separate objects, one for parent and one for child then why would you expect them to share that in that hierarchy? When you create a `social` object and then construct `newUser` within it, then why create a separate `newUser` as well?

Comment: This is an abbreviated example. The social object will be inheriting methods from the parent which I do not show here.

Comment: @user2232681 , you might find this useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208

Answer (score 1):

Because `$x` is completely unrelated to `$y`.  To see what I mean, look at this example:

```
$x = new newUser($handler);
$x->showdbconn();  

$z = new newUser($handler);
$z->showdbconn();
```

Since you have created two **instances** of `newUser`, you have to give the database connection to each one separately.

The same is true in your example.  When you create a new `social` instance, it has to have the database connection passed to it the same way that *every* new `newUser` instance needs to have the database connection passed.