# Pass SQL database connection to PHP function

Tags: php, sql, function, reference, connection

I am calling a function from a second PHP file and I want to avoid creating the DB connection again. I am using this code but it does not work.

```
$Db = mysqli_init();
$Db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
$Db->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
$connection = $Db->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);

CheckTableMetrics($connection, $dbname, $table1, $table2, $metric1, $metric2, $date1, $date2, $start_date, $end_date);
```

I get errors out of the blue. If I put the first part of my code in the PHP file that contains the function everything works.

The errors I get :

> mysqli::query(): invalid object or resource mysqli

and

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

The code works fine if I just put the :

```
$Db = mysqli_init();
$Db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
$Db->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
```

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Does not work.. I **love** questions like these.. How are we magically supposed to know why it doesn't work? Turn on your error reporting and try to debug your code?!

Comment: What is `it does not work`?

Comment: try to use http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: You can create a singleton object for dbConnection. Also check this document -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/767329

Comment: Please show the function `CheckTableMetrics` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is fairly simple:

```
$connection = $Db->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
```

This is wrong. `real_connect()` returns a boolean marking success or failure, not a connected database object. Instead, you should send `$Db` into your function, and it will all work.

Comment: Well spotted - missed that completely

Comment: Great. It was so simple !

Comment: The simple problems are often the hardest to spot :)