# PDO factory pattern

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop, pdo

While trying out PHP with OOP, i came accross discussions on Stackoverflow about PDOs and not using globals and singletons. I saw this question 
[How to properly set up a PDO connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection) which shows a way to use factory pattern and anonymous function for PDOs. I just had trouble understanding one part

```
class StructureFactory
{
    protected $provider = null;
    protected $connection = null;

    public function __construct( callable $provider )
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function create( $name)
    {
        if ( $this->connection === null )
        {
            $this->connection = call_user_func( $this->provider );
        }
        return new $name( $this->connection );
    }
}
```

The part I didnot understand was

`return new $name( $this->connection );`

Is the `$name` a callback? Or is it an object? Why was `$this->conection` passed as the paramater ? Thank You in Advance

Comment: `$name` should be the classname for the `new` instance. Why is this code not well documented?

Comment: Maybe it will get a little clearer when you know that the variable `$this->connection` not holding a mysql connection, instead it holds an `PDO` instance.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `something = $factory->create('Something');` This is the way it was used. Can you explain it a bit more? I couln't understand how i can use the pdo inside another class method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Something {
   protected $PDO;
   public function __construct(\PDO $PDO){
      //after this, you can use the PDO instance in your class.
      $this->PDO = $PDO;
   }
}

//get an class instance that holds an refer to the PDO class
$something = $factory->create('Something');
```

- As you can see in the link_answer in you post `$provider` returns an `PDO` instance.
- If you know use `$factory->create('Something');` you get an class instance of `Something` where the PDO instance from `StructureFactory` is injected.

But in my opinion `StructureFactory::create()` is kinda useless. What if the given class has more constructor parameter? How do we set them with `create()`?

Normaly a `getInstance()` is enuff

```
public function getInstance()
{
    if ( $this->connection === null )
    {
        $this->connection = call_user_func( $this->provider );
    }
    return $this->connection;
}
```

I dont have read the link fully but with my version you can do outside the factory this

```
 $something = new Something($factory->getInstance(),$anotherParameter);
```

Comment: Oh, so `$something` can be `$anything = $factory->create('something');`?

Comment: @feetnappy You can call/name variables like you want. But `'something'` must be an declared class if you use `create()`. Test it with just `$factory->create('NonExistingClassName');` will give an `Fatal Error`

Comment: I see, now I understand this much better. That question was targetted towards more experienced programmers, and not for absolute starters like us, so thanks for answering simple questions like this.