# Function for database connection with a static variable

Tags: php, pdo

Source: phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-registration-form/

Function db() connects the database once and returns a new PDO object with the configuration defined in another file.

```
function db(): PDO
{
    static $pdo;

    if (!$pdo) {
        return new PDO(
            sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=UTF8", DB_HOST, DB_NAME),
            DB_USER,
            DB_PASSWORD,
            [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
        );
    }
    return $pdo;
}
```

The site says during the first call $pdo is not defined hence the statement inside if is executed and new PDO object is returned and during the second call the PDO object is returned since $pdo is a static variable. How does it not return a new PDO object again during the second call? Even if $pdo is static we have not assigned the PDO object to it. Wont it retain its null value?

Comment: I have to agree with you, this is weird. Have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet. I got stuck trying to understand this.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't do what the author says it will create a new connection every time, so it will still work, but very inefficiently. You can put an `echo "I made a new connection";` after the `if (!$pdo) {` to see if it does indeed make a new connection every time. I think it will.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in the author's code.

Comment: The whole thing makes no sense. Maybe this is what was intended: https://3v4l.org/pt5P1 . Seems like they didn't test their own code properly.

Comment: $pdo is never assigned, so how could it retain ANY value. https://3v4l.org/40rqv  It will just keep creating new connections when called.

Comment: Similar in intent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67682706/2943403