# Is there any downside with using the Ghost Lazy Loading pattern in this way?

Tags: php, class, pdo, wrapper

**About the duplicate vote: This question is about the downsides of this approach, not about how to make this work; You can see it in this way: that question asks how to do something and the answer says something useful, however, I ask about the downsides of the answer.**

TL;DR: will I encounter any technical difficulty by using this wrapper class later on? Why I haven't seen anything like this before?

I've been <strike>experimenting</strike> learning techniques for profiling recently and I found that creating the PDO instance is a place that could be optimized (~5ms). I don't need to use it in every call, however I'm creating it in every call from my code's structure. So, I just made this small class up:

```
<?php
namespace Library;

// Wrapper for \PDO. It only creates the rather expensive instance when needed.
// Use it exactly as you'd use the normal PDO object, except for the creation.
// In that case simply do "new \Library\PDO($args);" with the normal args
class PDO
  {
  // The actual instance of PDO
  private $db;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->args = func_get_args();
    }

  public function __call($method, $args)
    {
    if (empty($this->db))
      {
      $Ref = new \ReflectionClass('\PDO');
      $this->db = $Ref->newInstanceArgs($this->args);
      }

    return call_user_func_array(array($this->db, $method), $args);
    }
  }
```

To call it you only need to modify this line:

```
$DB = new \Library\PDO(/* normal arguments */);
```

And the type-hinting if you are using it to `(\Library\PDO $DB)`.

It works flawlessly. It's also blazing fast (~0.2ms) when not using the PDO object and only introduces those ~0.2ms delay when using it (completely negligible). Now, I'm still learning about proper OOP, namespaces and general code structure, so I think I'm not qualified enough as to answer my own question yet:

**Will I encounter any technical difficulty by using this wrapper class later on?** Why I haven't seen anything like this before? therefore, why is this not more common or even default PDO behaviour?

Note: I intend to extend it furthermore by adding few more methods.

Comment: Looks like a basic singleton pattern to me, but using reflection to instantiate in the way you'd do with a factory pattern

Comment: @MarkBaker, it's not exactly a factory pattern because there's only one class being created.

Comment: @MarkBaker lol that radical change on the comment was funny. It's also not singleton, since I'm passing it around (not global) and I allow for several instances of `\Library\PDO` to exist (not **single** ton).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly set up a PDO connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection)

Comment: OK, I'll rephrase, a multiton

Comment: @PeeHaa can you please provide some insight of how this question is related to that one? Neither my goal nor the means are similar to that link.

Comment: It does the exact same thing as you are trying to do only without reflection.

Comment: But please explain what the actual optimisations are for creating the PDO object.... because I can't particularly see where it's any faster than simply doing new \PDO

Comment: @MarkBaker, in every request that the \PDO object is not used. Basically I'm lazy loading the object without having to pass the initialization parameters all around; in another light, I'm combining them in a single entity that is compatible with the *traditional* PDO object. So, gaining in speed in some cases and not losing in complexity.

Comment: BTW I would say 5ms is also pretty negligible when looking at an entire request / execution but hey...

Comment: @PeeHaa, I can see how similar they are now. There's a difference though, that when creating the PDO object the arguments are passed in-situ, however this is small. A bigger difference would be about the nature of the question, I'm asking about downsides/technical problems with this approach, however now I have somewhere to start looking at. Thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: There is nothing wrong with this. This is a common optimization pattern, known as [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), as you also mention in the comments.

While it could be implemented in different ways than what you have done here, your approach looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I said lazy load thinking that it was normally done just by not doing something yet, not by giving the *problem* to another class in the way I did. I actually didn't realize that it was lazy load until commenting. After reading [that wikipedia's article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Ghost) and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9911787), what I did is actually called a Ghost.

Comment: Haven't heard about the "ghost" before. But yes, that is indeed a ghost you're making :)